# Fault tolerant setup of Asterisk and FreePBX using a dedicated line

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am attempting to configure a fault tolerant setup of Asterisk with FreePBX. Going over the docs, I see I need to configure Pacemaker. Not a problem in itself as I've used PCS before. I have 2 servers running RedHat 8 and have Asterisk + FreePBX installed.

The issue is, my SIP trunk is not available over the Internet, instead the provider has given me a dedicated fiber line on which a /30 subnet is available. Only 2 usable IP's. One is the gateway while other is (currently) configured on one of my servers. Provider gave me no credentials. His service is fixed to that line and that IP.

So what IP do I give to my second server? One alternative I see is to setup a third system and configure that as a STUN server. With that option, a bigger can of worms opens as client demands that every item must have failover. Two STUN's? Sheesh!

Any idea what to do?